# Fragment não está substituindo o layout marcado

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragment

Estou trabalhando num projeto de faculdade e eu estou tendo dificuldades em substituir um dado *layout* por um fragmento. O que está acontecendo é que, o fragmento não está substituindo o *layout* da *activity* mas sim, mesclando com ele.

Este é o bloco de código que chama o fragmento:

```
    botaoDeFalar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            String textoParaFragment = editTextPrincipal.getText().toString();
            bundle.putString("oqSeraFalado", textoParaFragment);
            TesteFragment testefragment = new TesteFragment();
            testefragment.setArguments(bundle);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.LayoutMain, testefragment).commit();
            oqSeraFalado = textoParaFragment;
            vamosFalar();
        }
    });
}
```

A variável `BotaoDeFalar` é um elemento do *layout* do MainActivity (button) que ao apertado, executa todo este bloco.

o ID LayoutMain, é o *layout* que contempla todos os outros elementos da Activity.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mikha.projetointegrador5android.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/LayoutMain">
```

Este é o Java do *fragment* em questão:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_teste, container, false);
    resultadoPalavra = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextViewTesteFragment);
    palavraDigitada = this.getArguments().getString("oqSeraFalado");
    resultadoPalavra.setText(palavraDigitada);
    return view;

}
```

O resultado disso quando executo a aplicação é que, ao invés do *fragment* substituir tudo que a gente vê na tela principal pelo XML do *fragment*, ele adiciona o XML do *fragment* com o XML da tela principal, como se mesclasse.

Comment: Relacionado [Ao mudar de fragment, o anterior fica visível por debaixo do novo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192224/2541)

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível substituir, dessa forma, o layout da activity pelo do fragment.

Em termos de layout, o que o método `replace()` faz é substituir o layout de um fragment, anteriormente adicionado ao view group indicado, pelo deste.
Se ao view group indicado não tiver sido adicionado nenhum fragment, o método adiciona este e inclui o seu layout no view group.

Para que ao adicionar um fragment o seu layout não fique mesclado com o outro conteúdo ele deve ser adicionado a um group view vazio incluído no layout da activity, normalmente um FrameLayout.

Assim, se quer substituir todo o conteúdo do layout da activity, esse layout deverá ter apenas um FrameLayout sem nada dentro, depois use dois fragments, o que já tem e outro para o conteúdo que tinha a activity.

Comment: Seria como se eu usasse uma tela em branco no main Activity e fosse jogando nela, o conteudo que eu quisesse separado por fragments? daí, se eu quisesse continuar seguindo oq qro, entao deveria usar um intent ao inves de fragment. certo?

Comment: Sim, é mais ou menos isso. Se não quiser usar dois fragments use duas activities. Substitua o fragment que tem por uma Activity e em vez de `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace()` use `startActivity()`

Comment: Entendi. mas me explica uma coisa... eu refiz o código, coloquei o elemento do layout do XML da MainActivity que será substituido pelo fragment, dentro de um FrameLayout. (no caso, é um EditText). Mas ele continua não substituindo! dentro do XML da tela principal, tem 1 frame layout e dentro dele um EditText. o usuario digita algo no edit text, aperta o botao e o fragment é chamado no lugar deste Frame layout. Continua não substituindo, apenas mesclando =\

Comment: Você tem de dar um nome a esse FrameLayout e usá-lo no `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace()`. O FrameLayout não deve ter nada dentro.

Comment: O replace só substitui o conteúdo do FrameLayout se este tiver sido colocado por outro Fragment.